# addEventListener to a body to toggle back navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, responsive

I'm struggling to find a way to add an event listener to the document that makes the navbar toggle back without having to reach the burger menu.

I have been thinking about using:

```
document.body.addEventListener("onclick", function{  

 } );
```

But I don't know how I should mention the toggle effect

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");

  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
  });
};

navSlide();
```

Comment: Use `click`, not `onclick` for adding the event listener. Also, can you create a Codepen?

Comment: First create a state variable and it states the current status of the navbar. Now check if the navbar is open then close it, otherwise leave.

Comment: Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/revatto/pen/BaoQOZN

Comment: You code is already toggling the nav. What do you expect?

Comment: I want my navbar to toggle back when I click in the body, not only in the burger menu

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation to check if you're not clicking on the burger icon, and then remove the `nav-active` class.

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (!['fas','burger'].some(el => e.target.classList.contains(el))) {
              nav.classList.remove("nav-active");
 }
});
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/rajatkhare/pen/MWabqNG?editors=1011) is the updated Codepen.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Now it makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: Please upvote and mark my response as the answer if it helped.